# Converting Emoji to UTF

Tags: php, encoding

Hopefully my title makes sense I am not very good with character encoding. Anyway I have an application and I sometimes get input that looks like this ❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️❤️ and then it's saved to my db which is utf-8 encoded and it looks like this â¤ï¸â¤ï¸â¤ï¸â¤ï¸â¤ï¸â¤. When the user then requests the information again it looks like the latter. How can I save this data to my database and return it to the user looking the same as it was sent to me? I have looked around for some libraries that would do this but wasn't able to find any.

Comment: You need to be more precise *when and where* it looks like random garbage. If it's just your database viewer, then reconfigure that. If the page output is wrong, then your connection or HTML doesn't really have the proper encoding/charset set.

Comment: Thanks, the question you related it to will get me headed in the right direction.